# How i can tie MongoDB and Solr together in easy way

Tags: java, apache, mongodb, solr

I just couldn't able to configure the SOLR to get the documents from existing MONGODB. Even Google search for same dint gave me anything worth. Is there any tutorial, video to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

In a past life, we tailed the oplog and used that to feed info to solr.